# Scuffed gifs tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have a class that takes care of gifs on my tkinter app, it works for some gifs, but is scuffed for others.

```
class Animate(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        im.seek(0)
        frames = duration = 0
        while True:
            try:
                frames += 1
                duration += im.info['duration']
                im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
            except EOFError:
                self.delay = int(duration/frames)
                break

        first = seq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp.convert('RGBA')
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)
```

Here is the gif input that didn't work: [image]

It blinks and is all scuffed, here is a frame of it:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since nobody answered I went and put a lot of answers together and somehow made a working code, it is ugly, probably has more stuff than it needs, but works:

```
class Animate(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        seq = self.unpack_gif(filename)

        im.seek(0)
        frames = duration = 0
        while True:
            try:
                frames += 1
                duration += im.info['duration']
                im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
            except EOFError:
                self.delay = int(duration/frames)
                break

        first = seq[0]
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def unpack_gif(self,src):
        # Load Gif
        image = Image.open(src)

        # Get frames and disposal method for each frame
        frames = []
        disposal = []
        for gifFrame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image):
            disposal.append(gifFrame.disposal_method)
            frames.append(gifFrame.convert('RGBA'))

        # Loop through frames, and edit them based on their disposal method
        output = []
        lastFrame = None
        thisFrame = None
        for i, loadedFrame in enumerate(frames):
            # Update thisFrame
            thisFrame = loadedFrame

            # If the disposal method is 2
            if disposal[i] == 2:
                # Check that this is not the first frame
                if i != 0:
                    # Pastes thisFrames opaque pixels over lastFrame and appends lastFrame to output
                    lastFrame.paste(thisFrame, mask=thisFrame.convert('RGBA'))
                    output.append(lastFrame)
                else:
                    output.append(thisFrame)

            # If the disposal method is 1 or 0
            elif disposal[i] == 1 or disposal[i] == 0:
                # Appends thisFrame to output
                output.append(thisFrame)

            # If disposal method if anything other than 2, 1, or 0
            else:
                raise ValueError('Disposal Methods other than 2:Restore to Background, 1:Do Not Dispose, and 0:No Disposal are supported at this time')

            # Update lastFrame
            lastFrame = loadedFrame

        return output

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)
```

For the code to work I had to change:

```
frames.append(gifFrame.convert('P'))
```

To:

```
frames.append(gifFrame.convert('RGBA'))
```

So it has to do with P/RGBA conversion.